# How can I branch based on the status of wget?

Tags: linux, bash, operators, wget, rpm

I'm busy compiling a script to automatically install MySQL on Linux by sending a PuTTy window a number of commands.

The issue I'm having is that the download link of the one repository keeps on changing, I need to have a prompt pop up if the link is not accessible.

Here's what I got so far:

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm 
&& echo "WE GOT IT" || echo "URL Invalid, Please specify new URL:" 
&& read newurl && wget $newurl
```

But on running the result regardless of if the file exists is: 1. The first file will download, it will display either echo message and then it will wait on the read newurl command for user input and then wget that new variable.

How do I make the whole second half after the "||" only occur if the first url doesn't work?

Comment: Ouch! Your code makes my eyes bleed.

Comment: What shell are you working in? It probably also has some kind of `if` and `else`.

Comment: By the way, what language is this coded? PHP?

Comment: @CodeGnome - Haha, well.... Thanks? It's simply download file and echo or echo, wait for input and download new file. (That's what it is supposed to be).

Comment: @madziikoy and choroba, I'm using BASH scripting, linux style.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess @CodeGnome's answer logic below should help.

Comment: You have this tagged "`rpm`" - is this in an RPM install script of some kind (e.g. `%pre`)? If so, it is considered *very* bad form to attempt to read something from the user at RPM install-time; possibly not even allowed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Refactor Your Code

Your code is too contorted. While you could improve it with braced expressions, you're much better off refactoring your logic into if/else statements. As an (untested) example:

```
if wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
then
    echo 'We got it!'
else
    read -p 'URL invalid. Please specify new URL: '
    wget "$REPLY"
fi
```

Comment: Wow... Although I didn't use this example completely. What you said about braced expressions made sense and after adding brackets, everything works!

Comment: Final code:

`wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm || ( echo "URL Invalid, Please specify new URL:" && read newurl && wget $newurl )`

Comment: @Skowt I'm glad that helped. However, keep in mind that readability is often more important than conciseness. In many cases, an if/else branch is more readable six months from now than a series of `&&` operators. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @Skowt: Don't use `( cmd )` -- that creates a subshell, which can have unexpected effects. Instead use `{ cmd; }` or better yet `if then else fi`. One of the lessons you should take away from this is that readabilty *matters*, not just six months from now but as you're writing the code itself. The original problem occurred because you didn't understand what your code did *as you wrote it*, which never would've occurred if you weren't valuing terseness over clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm 
&& echo "WE GOT IT" && exit || echo "URL Invalid, Please specify new URL:" 
&& read newurl && wget $newurl


Add "exit" on left side of ||  with && operator ,,if the left argument is true then it will download that file and exit from terminal otherwise prompt for new url
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as I have a list of commands that also have to run after this one (all in a screen), so exiting is not an option. Thanks though for the attempt *thumbs up*